# Proper way to pass functions between distant components

Tags: reactjs

In my top level component i have:

```
<NavigationComponent />
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route component={SomeComponent} />
    ...
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

now, `NavigationComponent` have a `delete` icon which when clicked should call a function. I want that function to come from `SomeComponent` (or some other components from whatever active route is).

I’ve tried wrapping all routes into context, but it feels so entangled.

Other option was to pass `setDeleteCallback` to `SomeComponent` which would (in `componentDidMount`) set the callback and then pass that to `NavigationComponent` through render props. Also feels entangled.

Is there some best practice way to do this kind of plumbing?

ps. i dont need coded solution, just an idea.

Comment: You should take a look at [react-redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react), it does exactly what you want

Comment: @mthrsj i do use redux but i dont want my redux state to contain functions.

Comment: A state shouldn't necessarily contain functions. You can dispatch an action, as with any other case.

Comment: Not, that's not the idea. The `NavigationComponent` emit an action, and the `SomeComponent` detect the change through `componentDidUpdate` and then call the desired function. What do you think?

Comment: @mrhrsj how would navigation know which action data to include and which delete action to disptch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this idea, sorry just as I wanted to write code did not put it in comments

```
state={onDelete:()=>{}}

onDeleteHandler=func=>{this.setState({onDelete:func})}

   <NavigationComponent onDelete={this.state.onDelete}/>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route component={()=><SomeComponent onDeleteHandler={this.onDeleteHandler}/>} />
        ...
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

now `someComponent` should send its desired delete function back here, maybe on `componentDidMount` and `NavigationComponent` will receive it on `componentDidUpdate` as anew `prop`

Comment: thanks for your input! yes, thats one option i’ve tried (with render props, tought). i will upvote for now just to see if someone else comes up with something we overlooked. if not, i’ll accept it.